# Grepping a word buried in a <p> on a website

Tags: html, unix, web, grep

I am having trouble grepping a word on a website. This is the command I'm using

wget -q http://bcbioinformaticsgrad.ca/our-faculty/james-piret/ | grep 'medical' 
which is returning nothing, when it should be returning

[name of the website]:Many recent developments in biological and medical
.

.

.

.

.

.
The overall goal of what I'm trying to do is find a certain word within all the links of the website

My script is written like this

```
#!/bin/bash

#$1 is the parent website
#This pipeline obtains all the links located on a website
wget -qO- $1 | grep -Eoi '<a [^>]+>' |  grep -Eo 'href="[^\"]+"' | cut -c 7- | rev | cut -c 2- | rev > .linksLocated

#$2 is the word being looked for
#This loop goes though every link and tries to locate a word
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        wget -q $line | grep "$2"
done < .linksLocated

#rm .linksLocated
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wget doesn't put the downloaded file to standard output, so it's trying to grep the word from nothing (since you added the `-q` flag).

Add `-O -` to print the page to stdout:

```
wget -q http://bcbioinformaticsgrad.ca/our-faculty/james-piret/ -O - | grep 'medical'
```

I see you used it with the *first* wget in your script, so just add it to the second one, too.

It's also possible to use `curl`, which does that by default, without any parameters:

```
curl http://bcbioinformaticsgrad.ca/our-faculty/james-piret/ | grep 'medical'
```

---

Edit: this tool is super useful when you actually need to select certain HTML elements in the downloaded page, might suit some use cases better than grep: https://github.com/ericchiang/pup